# Lost connection to MySQL server during query в Telegram боте

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, telegram-bot

Я написал Telegram бота и он отлично функционирует, но через несколько часов после запуска выдает ошибку:

> 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Как я могу исправить эту ошибку? Бот работает на удаленном сервере на базе Linux с командной строки. Использую mysql.connector, подключаюсь к базе так:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="<имя пользователя>", password="<пароль>", database="<имя базы данных>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно увеличить wait_timeout и interactive_timeout.

[Решение здесь](https://ixnfo.com/izmenenie-wait_timeout-i-interactive_timeout-v-mysql.html)